# Activate web scoped feature on site definition

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm creating a site definition with a web-scoped feature that creates a subsite on the current site. I want to activate this feature on the site when an user creates a site based on that definition.

The feature works normally when I activate it, the problem is that I get the following error when I try to create a site based on the definition:

Feature with Id 'Id' is not installed in this farm and cannot be added to this scope.

I tried to change the scope to Farm, but it gets me the error "Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb'", also, I guess it doesn't make sense to have this feature farm-scoped.

My site definition 'web features' node contains:

```
    <WebFeatures>
            <Feature ID="6e512cb1-1a3f-43d6-a756-55c1a9eadd2c" />
    </WebFeatures>
```

My Feature Receiver method is:

```
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
        if (!web.Webs["subsite1"].Exists)
        {
            web.Webs.Add("subsite1");
            web.Update();
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if anyone needs more information.

Comment: howdy! I'd love to know if you've figured something out about this since you had this issue - workaround or solution, etc... I'm having a similar issue with a solution handed to me, so I'm trying to work through it and troubleshoot right now, but would appreciate any advice

Answer (score 2):

Open the Feature designer and select Scope: WebApplication

Answer (score 0):

```
<SiteFeatures>

    <Feature ID="C85E5759-F323-4EFB-B548-443D2216EFB5" />

    <Feature ID="A392DA98-270B-4e85-9769-04C0FDE267AA" />

    <Feature ID="7C637B23-06C4-472d-9A9A-7C175762C5C4" />

</SiteFeatures>

<WebFeatures>

    <Feature ID="00BFEA71-DE22-43B2-A848-C05709900100" />

    <Feature ID="00BFEA71-E717-4E80-AA17-D0C71B360101" />

</WebFeatures>

<Modules>

    <Module Name="Home" />

</Modules>
```